# Canceling a Flask backend process from a Web-based client

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-requests

I have a Flask application running at backend, and delivering some data to a client Web application through some endpoints. E.g.

```
@app.route('/extract_entities_from_matching_docs', methods=['POST'])
def extract_entities_from_matching_docs():
   data = request.form
   entities = storage.get_entities_in_docs_by_keywords(data[“keywords”])
   return jsonify(entities)
```

This is just an example, but the thing is sometimes, these kinds of methods take too much time to process, and the user may want to cancel the processing from the client (e.g. imagine you have a “Cancel” button on the client).

My question is: how can I cancel a running process at backend from the frontend? I thought that I may include a flag in the loops, so if the flag is set to true it continues looping and processing, otherwise, it just returns. But the problem with such a simple alternative is: what if the client just closes the browser’s tab? The process will continue running at the backend with no reason to do it. Maybe by posting to another flag from the client every x minutes, to make the backend know that there is a client waiting for the response. But maybe there is a more elegant solution that I'm ignoring.

I’m not really into the backend, but I need to solve this. So, can you suggest me any other alternative? Something to read? Or do you know if is there any good practice to face this?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is not easily possible. Generally the solution is to not bother and keep the request running in the background and just live with it. In the end most requests will probably not be "cancelled" and thus the overhead for developing this kind of solution outweighs the minor benefits.

If your tasks are really long-running (and with that I mean minutes or even much more), then you should off-load them to something like Celery tasks. In that case, you can keep a reference to the task ID and revoke it (passing `terminate=True` should deal with an already-running task as well).

Comment: Yeah, mine are long running (not minutes but almost a day)

Comment: In that case you absolutely need to off-load them to a background task manager.